# Effectively read multiple excel sheets from an xlsx excel workbook in SAS 9.4M7

Tags: sas, xlsx

I am trying to read multiple sheets from an excel workbook (xlsx format) in SAS. Instead of using two separate proc imports, is there a way to simultaneously read multiple excel sheets from an excel workbook? My code thus far is as follows:

```
proc import datafile= "&loc.\&exid..xlsx"
    out=exp                        
    dbms=xlsx replace; 
        sheet="Sheet1";
run;

proc import datafile= "&loc.\&exid..xlsx"
    out=dt                       
    dbms=xlsx replace; 
        range="'Sheet5'$A2:AB10000";
        getnames=yes;
run;
```

It is taking ~1.40 secs to read both of these excel sheets from one excel workbook, how do I reduce the time it takes to read xlsx workbook in SAS.

Comment: Why not just use PROC COPY?  `libname wb xlsx "filename.xlsx"; proc copy inlib=wb out=work; run;`

Comment: Thanks @Tom, how do I restrict SAS to copy just two out of the eleven xlsx excel sheets from the workbook? The other sheets are not valid SAS names, and I am getting an error which says 'The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors'.

Comment: @Tom, I used the select statement in Proc copy, it works, but it is taking much longer ~2.4 secs, is there a way to reduce this time?

Comment: Best way to improve performance is not use XLSX as the storage format.  SAS can read text files (like a CSV file) extremely quickly. And you can read multiple text files in one data step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SAS/CONNECT, you can run the two imports in parallel with `rsubmit`. I tested this out on an Excel file and it did not give any simultaneous access errors. Since each import is only about 1.4 seconds, this might take longer in aggregate since it needs to spin up two new SAS sessions to run each import.

```
options autosignon  = yes
        connectwait = no
        sascmd      = '!sascmd'
        ;

libname worklib "%sysfunc(getoption(work))";

/* Send over macro variables to rsubmit sessions */
%syslput _USER_ / remote=session1;
%syslput _USER_ / remote=session2;

rsubmit remote=session1 inheritlib=(worklib);
    proc import datafile= "&loc.\&exid..xlsx"
        out=worklib.exp                        
        dbms=xlsx replace; 
        sheet="Sheet1";
    run;
endrsubmit;

rsubmit remote=session2 inheritlib=(worklib);
    proc import datafile= "&loc.\&exid..xlsx"
        out=worklib.dt                       
        dbms=xlsx replace; 
        range="'Sheet5'$A2:AB10000";
        getnames=yes;
    run;
endrsubmit;
```

Comment: you are right, this is taking a bit longer than the two proc import statements.

Comment: don't imagine you could run them in parallel anyway, because SAS will lock the excel files.